# jQuery Call a Function in Addition to some other code

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to call a function into another function to get rid of some redundant code. The 'test' function is a standard piece of repetitive code, so I don't want to keep writing it out along with the custom animation.

```
(function test() {
    do this
});    

/* =========================Standard code========================= */
$(function () {
$('#div').click(EXECUTE THE 'TEST' FUNCTION HERE AND THEN...function() {
    $('#timeline').stop().animate({
        left : "+=500px"
    });
});
```

});

Here is the solution thanks to the kind guys below:

```
function test() {
    do this
}

/* =========================Standard code========================= */
$(function () {
$('#div').click(function() {
    test();
    $('#timeline').stop().animate({
        left : "+=500px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with:

```
$(function () {
$('#div').click(function() {
    test();
    $('#timeline').stop().animate({
        left : "+=500px"
    });
});
```

??

Comment: Not sure why but this isn't calling my function...
I've updated my question so you can see my real code with your suggestion in there, any ideas why this isn't working :-s

Comment: OK, I've just realised why it's not working, it's because there wasn't a dollar sign in front of my first function test. However, putting a $  in front of it executes the code immediately when the page loads, and I don't want that. Any idea how to stop the code from firing until I want it to?

Comment: 2 questions - does the test() function work on it own ( i.e. get rid of the timeline.stop code )? And does the timeline.stop code work process with the test() in there?

Comment: Got it, just needed to remove the round braces as per @deepak's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You would put your call to `test()` above the `$('#timeline')....` line.

Answer (score 1):

why you are using round braces around the test() function?

Can you try with an ALERT box in test() function?